# Copying Data from a Word Table into an Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am copying data from particular cells in a Word Table into particular cells in a spreadsheet. The actual code gets the right data into the right cells. However, the data seems to have Chr(7) (BEL) and a Char(13) (Carriage Return) at the end of the numeric value. Pardon if this is known problem, but is there a way to just get the numerical value in the word table. My extract of code is:

```
      With d.Tables(2)
                 
                    For j = 4 To 7
                    ReDim HoldValues(NumQuest(j))
                    Offset = 0
                    For irow = 2 To NumQuest(j) + 1
                        HoldValues(irow - 1) = d.Tables(2).Cell(irow, WordCol(j)).Range.Text
                        ws.Cells(PasteLocn(j) + Offset, chooseColumn) = HoldValues(irow - 1)
                        Offset = Offset + 1
                    Next irow
                Next j
                                 
        
    End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trim off the "end of cell" characters:

```
Dim v
'...
'...
With d.Tables(2)
    For j = 4 To 7
        ReDim HoldValues(NumQuest(j))
        Offset = 0
        For irow = 2 To NumQuest(j) + 1
            v  = .Cell(irow, WordCol(j)).Range.Text   '<<<
            HoldValues(irow - 1) = Left(v, Len(v)-2)  '<<<
            ws.Cells(PasteLocn(j) + Offset, chooseColumn) = HoldValues(irow - 1)
            Offset = Offset + 1
        Next irow
    Next j
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Tim Williams' solution provides a straightforward approach.

As an alternative, if you want to extract just the plain text from the Word table without any extra steps, you could try:

```vb
    Dim wCell, txtInTable 

    For irow = 2 To NumQuest(j) + 1
        ' Get it with Word VBA
        Set wCell = d.Tables(2).Cell(irow, WordCol(j)).Range
        txtInTable = d.Range(Start:=wCell.Start, End:=wCell.End - 1).Text
        HoldValues(irow - 1) = txtInTable 
                
        ws.Cells(PasteLocn(j) + Offset, chooseColumn) = HoldValues(irow - 1)
        Offset = Offset + 1
    Next irow
```